# Django crashes when I run makemigrations and migrate

Tags: python, django

When I want to update my code on server, I obtain this error after `python manage.py migrate`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/casista-root/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "properties_property" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "properties_property"."locality" FROM "properties_pro...
```

I've tried deleting all migrations and recreate it, but when I execute `python manage.py makemigrations` the error appears another time.

I've also tried to drop and create database but it seems that never work to solve the issue.

Is the first time it crashes.. am I making something wrong?

**Update: add choices.py**

I fix it commenting next code:

from properties.models import Property

```
CITIES = (
    ('any', 'Cualquiera'),
)

# cities = Property.objects.all().values_list('locality', flat=True)
# for city in cities:
#     ALL_CITIES = CITIES + ((city.lower(), city),)
```

Can't I do it?? And how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Somewhere you have some code that is doing a query at module or class level

Comment: try deleting the database as well as all the migrations.. not just drop table

Comment: @johnashu don't advise to drop the database please. That should be a very last resort in extreme situations after backups have been taken. Usually these problem *do not* need such drastic solutions

Comment: @DanielRoseman this afternoon I will update with all traceback

Comment: @e4c5 please read the op   question  properly before criticising .

Comment: @johnashu and still suggesting to drop the database is very poor advise

Comment: I've updated my traceback

Comment: I think the problem could be in choices.py - as @Daniel Roseman said "Somewhere you have some code that is doing a query at module or class level". Could you show the choices.py? Where is 
"for city in cities" code? Outside method or class?

Comment: Yes I think you need to post the forms and choices modules.

Comment: @e4c5 he had already dropped the table.  I suggested he delete the database.  deleting a database with no tables is not bad advice. Especially in django.  It has solved many as issue for me quickly.  It is common advice in django.  If you do not care  about keeping the data.. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html